# Unable to install php7.0 on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu

I want to install php7 or 7.1 in Ubuntu but i can't

I try with this code :

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install -y php7.1
```

and this is result :

```
sudo: unable to resolve host myvps
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1'
```

Also for PHP 7.0

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'
```

But i know i can install php5 but i don't want !
se result of this commend `php -v`

```
root@myvps:~# php -v
The program 'php' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install php5-cli
```

and here is my ubuntu information :

```
root@myvps:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:        15.04
Codename:       vivid
```

whats wrong ? is it possible to solve this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-cache search php7.0-`?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-cache search php7` to find the exact package name.

Comment: ` sudo apt-get install php7.0 `  it is correct , but not work only in this `vps`  realy i dont know why , also i reinstall `os` and try and no any result !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about package management and not programming.  Try https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/705893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All code is correct however we need to attention to Kernel release end of life it is so important !

My problem is from here !

and for solve that we have 2 option :

- first upgrade Kernel release (recommended)
- second use from [this hack](https://askubuntu.com/a/997098) (at your own risk)

Answer (score 0):

Try without adding any repositories.

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Comment: available in question  `E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0'`

Comment: your ubuntu version is now out of support, update your ubuntu and try again.